# How do I submit form without page reload taking into consideration the php script?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So basically I have to work on this loan calculator loancalc.000webhostapp.com

I have looked at other pages on this site "how to submit form without page reload?" but this isn't completely relevant to what i'm working on. So far i've added this into the jquery part of the page...

```js
jQuery('qis-register').on('submit', 'input', function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var name = $("input#yourname").val();
        var email = $("input#youremail").val();
        if (name == ""){
            $("input#yourname").focus;
            return false;
        }
        else{

        }
        if (email == ""){
            $("input#youremail").focus;
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But i'm told there is also two other scripts that I need to work with, I'm not really too experienced with php so not sure what's going on, the two php scripts I have to work with are called quick-interest-slider.php and register.php,

```
//qis_verify_application in register.php

    function qis_verify_application(&$values, &$errors) {
    $application = qis_get_stored_application();
    $register = qis_get_stored_application_messages();

    $arr = array_map('array_shift', $application);
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if ($application[$key]['type'] == 'multi') {
            $d = explode(",",$application[$key]['options']);
                foreach ($d as $item) {
                    $values[$key] .= $values[$key.$item];
                }
        }
        if ($application[$key]['required'] == 'checked' && $register['use'.$application[$key]['section']] && (empty($values[$key]) || $values[$key] == 'Select...')) 
            $errors[$key] = 'error';
        }

    $filenames = array('identityproof','addressproof');

    foreach($filenames as $item) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES[$item]['tmp_name'];
        $name = $_FILES[$item]['name'];
        $size = $_FILES[$item]['size'];
        if (file_exists($tmp_name)) {
            if ($size > $register['attach_size']) $errors['attach'.$item] = $register['attach_error_size']; 
            $ext = strtolower(substr(strrchr($name,'.'),1));
            if (strpos($register['attach_type'],$ext) === false) $errors['attach'.$item] = $register['attach_error_type'];
        }
    }
    return (count($errors) == 0);   
}

//qis_process_application in register.php

    function qis_process_application($values) {
    global $post;
    $content='';
    $register = qis_get_stored_register ('default');
    $applicationmessages = qis_get_stored_application_messages();
    $settings = qis_get_stored_settings();
    $auto = qis_get_stored_autoresponder();
    $application = qis_get_stored_application();
    $message = get_option('qis_messages');

    $arr = array_map('array_shift', $application);

    if ($message) {
        $count = count($message);
        for($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++) {
        if ($message[$i]['reference'] == $values['reference']) {
            $values['complete'] = 'Completed';
            $message[$i] = $values;
            update_option('qis_messages',$message);
            }
        }    
    }

    $filenames = array('identityproof','addressproof');

    $attachments = array();
    if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    }
    add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'qis_upload_dir' );

    $dir = (realpath(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/qis/') ? '/uploads/qis/' : '/uploads/');
    foreach($filenames as $item) {
        $filename = $_FILES[$item]['tmp_name'];
        if (file_exists($filename)) {
            $name = $values['reference'].'-'.$_FILES[$item]['name'];
            $name = trim(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9. ]/', '', $name));
            $name = str_replace(' ','-',$name);
            $_FILES[$item]['name'] = $name;
            $uploadedfile = $_FILES[$item];
            $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
            $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
            array_push($attachments , WP_CONTENT_DIR .$dir.$name);
        }
    }

    remove_filter( 'upload_dir', 'qis_upload_dir' );

    $content = qis_build_complete_message($values,$application,$arr,$register);

    qis_send_full_notification ($register,$values,$content,true,$attachments);

    qis_send_full_confirmation ($auto,$values,$content,$register);
}
```

function qis_loop in quick-interest-slider.php

```
function qis_loop($atts) {

    $qppkey = get_option('qpp_key');
    if (!$qppkey['authorised']) {
        $atts['formheader'] = $atts['loanlabel'] = $atts['termlabel'] = $atts['application'] = $atts['applynow'] = $atts['interestslider'] = $atts['intereselector']= $atts['usecurrencies'] = $atts['usefx'] = $atts['usedownpayment'] = false;
        if ($atts['interesttype'] == 'amortization' || $atts['interesttype'] == 'amortisation') $atts['interesttype'] = 'compound';
    }

    global $post;

    // Apply Now Button

    if (!empty($_POST['qisapply'])) {
        $settings = qis_get_stored_settings();
        $formvalues = $_POST;
        $url = $settings['applynowaction'];
        if ($settings['applynowquery']) $url = $url.'?amount='.$_POST['loan-amount'].'&period='.$_POST['loan-period'];
        echo "<p>".__('Redirecting....','quick-interest-slider')."</p><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=$url' />";
        die();

    // Application Form

    } elseif (!empty($_POST['qissubmit'])) {
        $formvalues = $_POST;
        $formerrors = array();
        if (!qis_verify_form($formvalues, $formerrors)) {
            return qis_display($atts,$formvalues, $formerrors,null);
        } else {
            qis_process_form($formvalues);
            $apply = qis_get_stored_application_messages();
            if ($apply['enable'] || $atts['parttwo']) return qis_display_application($formvalues,array(),'checked');
            else return qis_display($atts,$formvalues, array(),'checked');
        }

    // Part 2 Application

    } elseif (!empty($_POST['part2submit'])) {
        $formvalues = $_POST;
        $formerrors = array();
        if (!qis_verify_application($formvalues, $formerrors)) {
            return qis_display_application($formvalues, $formerrors,null);
        } else {
            qis_process_application($formvalues);
            return qis_display_result($formvalues);
        }

    // Default Display

    } else {
        $formname = $atts['formname'] == 'alternate' ? 'alternate' : '';
        $settings = qis_get_stored_settings();
        $values = qis_get_stored_register($formname);
        $values['formname'] = $formname;
        $arr = explode(",",$settings['interestdropdownvalues']);
        $values['interestdropdown'] = $arr[0];
        $digit1 = mt_rand(1,10);
        $digit2 = mt_rand(1,10);
        if( $digit2 >= $digit1 ) {
            $values['thesum'] = "$digit1 + $digit2";
            $values['answer'] = $digit1 + $digit2;
        } else {
            $values['thesum'] = "$digit1 - $digit2";
            $values['answer'] = $digit1 - $digit2;
        }
        return qis_display($atts,$values ,array(),null);
    }
}
```

Do I have to edit any of the php and I also don't know what I have to write considering the php.

Answer (score 0):

You can use what is called Ajax to submit the data to the server via POST.

Create a button and give it a class of qis-register, then give each of your input fields a class that matches it's name. Then just add that field to the data object that I have following the format within it.

```js
jQuery(document).on('click', '.qis-register', function(){
        
        var name = $("input#yourname").val();
        var email = $("input#youremail").val();
        if (name == ""){
            $("input#yourname").focus;
        }
        else if (email == ""){
            $("input#youremail").focus;
        }
        else{
          jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "your_php_here.php",
      data: {
                    name:name,
                    email:email,
                    qissubmit:$(".qissubmit").val(),
                    qisapply:$(".qisapply").val(),
                    part2submit:$(".part2submit").val(),
         },
      done: function(msg){
     console.log(msg);
      }
  });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know what the values for

".qissubmit",
".qisapply",
".part2submit"

Would be?

Comment: @StevenCurnow, I don't know. They are in your php, so I referenced them.